# Is there an OEM version of Ubuntu 15.10

Tags: 15.10

I seem to recall that Ubuntu 15.10 has an OEM Install option.  Is this the case?

Comment: Yes, this is the case ;-)

Comment: +1 for lmddgtfy. Didn't know Duckduckgo had an equivalent to lmgtfy!

Comment: don't confuse us yes if you will buy certified machine pre-installled with Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

When booting to Live CD of Ubuntu 15.10, and the stickman image next to the equal sign and the keyboard on the bottom of the screen, Just press any key, to bypass auto-boot and go to menu, Select the lauguage and then press F4, it will list you modes, (Normal, OEM Install for manufacturers), Arrow-down key to OEM Install, and press Enter, then down-arrow key until "Install Ubuntu" is highlighted, Press Enter to start the installation.